# aptana studio with node.js express

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, eclipse-plugin, express, aptana

I just installed Aptana Studio and I am wondering whether do I need to install also [nodeeclipse](http://www.tomotaro1065.com/nodeclipse/) or [Enide](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-nodejs-ide#.Uh7nKE1hYu0) in order to use [express](http://expressjs.com/) together with [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you have any indication about why you should / shouldn't do it? Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Aptana studio does not provide any code completion for node.js code and I could not find out how to execute node.js code from Aptana. Therefore I thought on of the above plugins would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enide.p2f to install older JSDT and Nodeclipse into Aptana.

Check http://www.nodeclipse.org for news about TernIDE that will give completions and hint for express code.